# Selecting database values by specific interval dates, not working properly

Tags: php, date, datepicker, datetimepicker, between

HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="configuration/raportare/generate_orhideea.php">
<input type="text" name="reportrangeTwo" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Generează raport">
</form>
```

The form has a Jquery datarange input which allows me to select two dates simultaneously.

generate_orhideea.php file, where I substract each date with `explode()` function:

```
    //SOME CODE HERE
    // Create database variables
    require_once "../../configuration/db.php";
    $dates = $_POST['reportrangeTwo']; // E.g: 19-01-2017 | 17-02-2017
    $first_date = explode(" ", $dates);
    $begin = $first_date[0];
    $end = $first_date[2];

    $rows = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM clienti_orhideea WHERE data_inregistrare between '$begin' and '$end' order by data_inregistrare asc");
    // loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
?>
```

If `$dates = 17-02-2017 | 17-02-2017` it will return me all the values from today.

If `$dates = 16-02-2017 | 16-02-2017` it will return me all the values from yesterday.

If `$dates = 19-01-2017 | 17-02-2017` it should return last 30 days but it  returns blank, because I don`t have any date starting with 19.

BUT, if `$dates = 11-02-2017 | 17-02-2017`, it will return me ALL the values from last 7 days, INCLUDING values from 14-01-2017. It is more than 7 days.

What can be the problem?

Comment: I think it takes only the first 2 numbers from the date and stops at first "-" . The entire string is 16-02-2017 but I think it looks for values starting just by first 2 numbers, 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert the dates you want to compare to a format that suits MySQL:

```
$rows = mysqli_query($connection, 
                       "SELECT * FROM clienti_orhideea 
                          WHERE data_inregistrare between
                            STR_TO_DATE('$begin', '%d-%m-%Y') AND
                            STR_TO_DATE('$end', '%d-%m-%Y') 
                          ORDER BY data_inregistrare ASC"
                    );
```

If you by some chance store the date as a varchar data type (you should always use `date`, `datetime` or any of the other date/time compatible datatypes in MySQL), you could try this:

```
$rows = mysqli_query($connection, 
                       "SELECT * FROM clienti_orhideea 
                          WHERE STR_TO_DATE(data_inregistrare, '%d-%m-%Y') between
                            STR_TO_DATE('$begin', '%d-%m-%Y') AND
                            STR_TO_DATE('$end', '%d-%m-%Y') 
                          ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(data_inregistrare, '%d-%m-%Y') ASC"
                    );
```

Comment: This will not return the day first. If I execute the query, NULL return. I am sure this is the answer, but i need to figure out fmt `'%d-%m-%Y'`

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE('17-02-2016', '%d-%m-%Y')` is only formatting a string to a real date format. In this case, you seem to use the format day-month-year as input for your WHERE-clause. What data type are you using for your column `data_inregistrare`?

Comment: varchar I am using.

Comment: You should be using the data type `date` or `datetime` for storing dates in MySQL. But I will update my answer to try to help you..

Comment: Ok, I will do this, but I need to find a way to reverse date from 2017-02-17 to 17-02-2017 before I export the excel file through `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);`

Comment: In my example, you only convert the date for usage in the where clause to get the date comparisons right.. The returning values should not be affected.... try my second suggestion and let me know how it works..

Comment: Ok, it works fine now when I changed data type to `date`. In my excel file the date is shown 2/17/2017, although I really want to show it at least 2017-02-17 if it is not possible 17-02-2017.

Comment: You can show the date in any format you like.. How it shows up in excel depends on your local excel settings for date formatting. Just specify the format in your SELECT-statement: `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(data_inregistrare, '%d-%m-%Y'), other_column_name, etc..` But if you already have converted into a date-format, you could use any other date formatting available in MySQL..

Comment: Thank you! Your answer gave me 2 choices. You are good! Thanks again! I will keep in mind your advice about using data type `date` for date columns.

Comment: I realised now that Excel 2013 is auto formatting the date. LOL

Comment: Great that it worked for you, thanks for accepting the answer.